# Rails 3.1 - find_or_create_by Not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this code ...

```
    recipient = User.find_or_create_by_email(params[:recipient_email],
        { :password => 'password',
        :password_confirmation => 'password',
        :first_name => 'First',
        :last_name => 'Last',
        :active => false })
```

which doesn't work. The recipient isn't saved in the database as it should be. However this ...

```
    recipient = User.find_or_create_by_email(params[:recipient_email],
        { :password => 'password',
        :password_confirmation => 'password',
        :first_name => 'First',
        :last_name => 'Last'})
```

does work in that it creates the recipient and saves it in the database, but the :active flag is now set to the default true.

In the User model I have ...

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :active
```

and

```
validates :active, :presence => true
```

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: I thought I couldn't when it wouldn't let me upvote some answers. There's obviously something I'm missing. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Ahhh... the big checkbox thing? OK, I've accepted a bunch of answers. Thanks for pointing the issues out @troutwine

Comment: No problem. I don't have anything for the question at hand, though. You might pass it by the people in #ror on irc.freenode.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `:active` is either true or false (or nil unless you defined a default value in your migration file). Maybe false is interpreted as non-present, I don't really know. BUT this is how I would do this:

Put `t.boolean :active, :default => false` in your file (or if you need to create a migration, do `change_column :table, :active, :boolean, :default => false`) and then remove your validation.

Every user is now saved as false unless you provide a param with a different value. If most of your users should be true (so the whole thingm, but vice-versa), then change it so. This makes your validation needless.

Hope I got the point of your problem.. otherwise, ignore me.

Comment: @pduesteler - thanks for chiming in. Here's my migration and if I understand what you're saying, I think I'm doing it already ...

    `class AddActiveToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :users, :active, :boolean, :default => true
      end
    end`

Am I missing something?

Comment: @pduesteler - Just removed the validation and everything works. The default is true and I can pass false. Not exactly sure **why**, but for now I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: like I thought, seems that false is interpreted as not-present. You're welcome.